# Bindable indexed in-Memory Data Scturcture

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, data-structures

I want to improve one of my current applications that uses ADO Data Sets. The application is standalone, no DBs. Almost everyone says that ADO Data set is an old stuff and a much better approach is using your own structures. For example I have the data model below (the same kind of model we usually use with Entity Framework):

```
public class Customer
{
      public int ID {get;set;}
      public string Value {get;set}
      public IEnumerable<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}

public class Order
{
      public int ID {get;set;}
      public string Value {get;set}
      public Customer Customer {get;set;}
}
```

I don't understand the next:
How to store class model in memory. Just in a simple `List<>`. It is not efficient with searching. In SQL we can make indexes for two often used columns and optimize our search. Can we do something similar (fast indexed search by multiple columns) in memory? If can, please explain me how. In DataTables we can use Primary Key as index.
Is a good data structure exist. A structure that allows binding to DataGrids, Fast indexed search by multiple columns, LINQ. Or we need to store everything in `List<>` or `Hashset<>` and prepare some additional structures for fast searching.

Comment: Before starting such a research, ask yourself "do I really need it"? 
My first choice for a fast lookup (and easiness in coding) would be a Dictionary, (or more dictionary with same values and different keys, as having different indexes on a db table).
but really, before searching for the quickest data structure in the world, try to understand if you really have a bottleneck and if changing your data structure will save you seconds or nanoseconds. (i.e. will my software users appreciate the difference?).

Comment: May be you've just answered my question. These is no such a universal data structure. I just need to use some collections and prepare some additional Hash-based structures for search. In my case the speed is really important. Now that's the exact problem I try to solve. Now everything works with DataTable.Select("col1 = ... and col <> ...") etc. Not my code, but my task is to speed it up.